# How to render a POST and make it show up on another page? in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create Car Rental website similar to Hyrecar. I created a form according to the Django tutorial "Working with forms", but I don't know how to render information I got from the POST forms. I want to make information(Booking Name,rental price ...etc) that I got from POST show up the car and its detail which is booked. Car is foreign key field in booking.i want to redirect it to the page showing that car which is booked .
for eg

1. **Booking name** : xyz
2. **Rental Price** : 123
3. **CAr** : carimage.jpg
   4 .

I want to redirect it to the page pop. if the user booked a car and post the form . after that redirect it to the pop.html  page and show the booking  detail that the user posted now .

**Forms.py**

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):

 class Meta:
     model = Booking
     widgets = {
         'times_pick': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class':'timepicker'}),

     }
     fields = ('booking_name','rental_price','book_car','customer_name','times_pick',)
```

**urls.py**

```
   [

   url(r'^booking/',views.BookingView.as_view(),name='car_booking'),

   url(r'^pop/$',views.PopView.as_view(),name='pop'),
 ]
```

**views.py**

```
  class CarDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'car_details'
    model = models.Car
    template_name = 'buggy_app/car_detail.html'

class BookingView(FormView):
   template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
   form_class = BookingForm
   models = Booking
   def form_valid(self, form):
       form.save()
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)

   success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
        try:
           kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
        except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
           kwargs['car'] = None

        return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

   def get_initial(self):
       initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()
       if 'car' in self.request.GET:
          try:
              initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])
           except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            pass
       return initial
```

**booking.html**

```
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">

  </form>
```

Comment: So you want to use posted values in **class BookingView(FormView)**

Comment: i want to show the car that the user booked.  you can say i want to show that car_details which is booked . fetching that id data and show to the pop.html. that you booked nissan and the price is thank you for your booking

Comment: Did you tried using AJAX?

Comment: No .  i didnt know about ajax

Comment: How to do with ajax

Comment: By the way, your model architecture is very bad... You can make it much structural, so it will be easy for you to work with data. From your question I understand that you should have car models (stored in different table), car images (stored in different table with foreign key to car model) and booking model (stored in different table with foreign key to car model) and so on.... so you have problems on step of building models and relation

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew https://pastebin.com/KKxkDXGf THESE ARE MY MODELS

Comment: add me in linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B2-39b091166/ we will discus your project solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
def save_form(request):
   args = {}
   form = BookCarForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       book = form.save(commit=False)
       book.book_car_mark = request.POST.get('car_mark')
       book.book_car_mmodel = request.POST.get('car_model')
       book.book_car_year = request.POST.get('car_year')
       book.book_car_mark = request.POST.get('car_mark')
       form.save()
       try:
           args['book'] = Book.objects.get(id=book.id)
       except:
           args['book'] = None
       if args['book'] is not None:
           return render(request, 'your_template.html', args)
       else:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/your/url/to-booking-form/')
```

Name of fields as name of models and templates are abstract, so it's just a working mechanism scheme

Comment: check out i had given more details what i want to do .

Comment: I've edited answer, try new one. By the way, start to biuld custom forms instead of model based django forms.